# Validar um Matcher

Tags: java, regex

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber como verificar se o *matcher* encontrou algo. 
Pois estou buscando informações dentro de um arquivo PDF e quando ele não encontrar nada gostaria de ter uma condição que escrevesse "Informação não encontrada"

```
while (matcherAut.find()) { //antes deste WHILE gostaria de ter um if e se o matcher não tiver encontrado nada escrever uma mensagem.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s0.*|\\s1.*|\\s2.*|\\s5.*|\\s6.*|\\s7.*|\\s8.*|\\s9.*|^0.*|^1.*|^2.*|^5.*|^6.*|^7.*|^8.*|^9.*"); // Segundo Filtro (Elimina os que não começam com 3|4)
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(matcherAut.group()).useDelimiter(pattern);
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(aut);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        aut = scanner.next();
        if (!linhasGravadas.contains(aut)) {
            System.out.println("Pagina: " + i);
            System.out.println("Autorização: " + matcherAut.group());
            /*System.out.println("Autorização: " + aut);
            gravarArq.println(aut);
            linhasGravadas.add(aut);*/
            Aut = Aut + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa REGEX pode ser escrita como `"(\\s|^)[12356789].*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o método [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) ou [matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) do [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), ambos retornam boolean.

No seu caso:

```
if (!marcher2.find()) {
    System.out.println("Informação não encontrada");
}
```

Comment: Respostas baseadas em links nao sao recomendadas. Tente elaborar uma resposta que seja autoexplicativa e contextualizada, servindo o link apenas para referencia.